# Calling UIWebView method from Another Class

Tags: java, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

OK, I'm sure it's simple but I will try to explain everything I'm doing in detail so someone could show me my mistakes. Xcode, iOS SDK 6.1, I'm using StoryBoard.

-I have my MenuViewController (View Controller) with some buttons. In Identity inspector I  have set my custom class. Every button has it's outlet in MenuViewController.h (using Ctrl drag). Every button is synthesized in MenuController.m and only thing I'm doing so far is setting background in -viewDidLoad Method in MenuViewController.m

-I have another WebViewController (View Controller with Navigation Bar, Bar Button and UIWebView). I have also created new class for that ViewController and set it in Identity inspector. WebView has it's outlet in WebViewController.h and it's synthesized in WebViewController.m

-I have made connection between those two ViewControllers also through Xcode. One button from my MenuViewController is opening WebViewController (I'v done that by Ctrl+Dragging that button to WebViewController and style is set to Modal). I'v done the same thing with button in NavigationBar of my WebViewController, made connection that is opening MenuViewController when clicked (something like Back button).

-Right now, that WebView is opening some webpage when -viewDidLoad method in WebViewController is called.

**What I WOULD LIKE TO DO is to set buttonPressed actions in my MenuViewController and for example, if one button is pressed, I want to switch to WebViewController and open some specific URL. If another button is pressed I want also to open that same WebViewController and load some different URL. This should not be hard but I would just like someone to show me the right way for calling method of webView from another class. I'm new in Objective C and only language I know so far is Java, so I'm a bit confused with this .h .m stuff, not sure where to declare what properly. Also if someone could compare what would something here in Objective-C look in Java, that would be great for understanding.**

Thanks folks!

Comment: Please show your code instead of just describing it.  This will allow us to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

I dont use storyboard and do some thing like this:

In your WebViewController .m file make a method some thing like this:

```
-(id)initWithURL:(NSString *)urlstring
{
    self = [super init];
    receivedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
    return self;
}
```

and in .h file declare an object of NSURL

```
NSURL *receivedURL;
```

and just above the @end

```
-(id)initWithURL:(NSString *)urlstring;
```

and in your viewDidLoad Method of WebViewController do

```
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:receivedURL]];
```

Now in your MenuViewController when ever the button action is performed do something like this:

```
WebViewController *webViewObj = [[WebViewController alloc]initWithURL:yourURLString];
[self presentModalViewController:webViewObj animated:YES];
```

Comment: In your appdelegate after initializing you MenuViewController
UINavigationController *navc=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuViewControllerObj];

Comment: I can't yet vote up, but this gave me ideas to resolve a lot of problems. Thanks :)